# How much longer does the M1-Max MacBook Pro battery last compared to the previous (non-M1-Max) model?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

How much longer the battery life of the most recent 16 inch MacBook Pro is relative to the next most recent 16 inch MacBook Pro (2019 model) under similar (preferably identical) work loads?

What I already know: I find many sites with statistics for the two machines in isolation, but these aren't necessarily useful because many test the machines under different usage loads, hence they are not like-for-like comparisons. It's important that both machines be made to do very similar workloads during the comparisons.

Comment: Apple publishes information about this on apple.com. But benchmarking as this highly depends on the actual use of the machine, so even if you find independent tests they may or may not be applicable to your situation depending on the workload tested. What kind of research have you already done, which specific workload are you interested in?

Comment: @nohillside I'll assume you read the question, so you probably gleaned that the type of workload isn't important so long as said workloads are identical so as to not compare apples to oranges. Please reopen it.

Comment: Maybe some background on why you consider it not to be important might help then. If one answers shows that for light web browsing the difference is factor 2, and another shows that for some heavy-duty video editing while participating in Teams conferences and mining bitcoins in the background the difference isn't relevant, which one do you consider the one to accept? What would you even to with the result?

Comment: @nohillside Regarding the result, it's quite specific to me, hence why I don't include it in the question, but since you ask, essentially I'm planning the logistics of some classes I'll be delivering via live stream, and assessing whether I can conduct them from an outdoors workstation (MBP connected via hotspot and running streaming software, recording software, an IDE, a browser, and a few other generic applications). The previous 16 inch model will get close to 3 hours, but some classes will go over 3 hours. However, some could go over significantly. *cont*

Comment: @nohillside Hence it's probably best to leave out specific use cases from the question, and simply focus on one or more general uses (so long as it's the *same* use on both machines).

Comment: But isn't the information available on apple.com as good as any then?

Comment: @nohillside I definitely can't prove that it isn't. And I'm reluctant to try to even make the case that it isn't (rabbit hole), but I will say this: if a company advertises its product, even a very reputable company, it's still not as reliable as a third party source doing so. Which is why I like to read reviews on things I buy, to supplement the info from the company. Anecdotally, every MBP upgrade I've made in the past has been great, but below where I had expected in 2 areas: compute and battery life. If someone has compared the 2 side by side, it will give a 'real world' comparison.

Comment: I'd drop [this](https://9to5mac.com/2021/10/18/new-macbook-pro-battery-life/) in as part of an answer if the question wasn't closed. But it appears the M1-Max 16 inch's battery life is approximately 91% longer for video playback, and 27% longer for wireless web use. These figures are based on the numbers in the tables on the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to be very hard to get data on this unless you can find some Youtuber running battery tests on both models.** The nature of the tasks is also likely to be significant, given that the M1s have hardware dedicated to certain tasks.

However, it is well known that the M1 CPUs are much more power-efficient than the old Intel CPUs -- indeed, the heat-generation on the Intels was one of the motivations for switching to the new architecture.

In short: the new M1 is going to be faster and last longer on battery for any given task than the old Intel MBP. How much so? *Pffffffft*.

** Here's a thorough review of the two models, which includes battery performance. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNMcMhFV0E4

Comment: Does the Max Tech review you link to compare the battery life of the two models?

Comment: @stevec He describes the power usage of each model for several of the tasks.

Comment: I scanned the chapters but couldn't spot the discussion on power usage. Do you know what time in the video it's discussed?

Comment: As I said: it is discussed as part of several of the discussions about various benchmarks. If you're interested in comparing the two machines, then I suggest you watch it.

Comment: I removed my upvote. I appreciate the attempt to help, but there's nothing of substance in the answer. I really do appreciate the help and am not being ungrateful. But I cannot verify that anything in the answer actually answers the question. I will watch the *Cenebench R23 Stress Test* chapter (15m14s - 18m18s) when I can, and if I find the parts you're referring to, I'll add them as a comment. I suspect I may still need to figure out how power consumption over time (which is what may be compared in the video) translates to the time each machine's battery lasts (given the batteries differ)